# Как можно прикрутить progressbar к копированию файлов

Tags: python, pyqt5

Всем привет. Есть `Progressbar`:

```
self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Dialog)
self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 651, 23))
self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
```

Есть функция копирования:

```
shutil.copytree(cur_dir + "/321321", cur_dir + "/folder2")
```

Как сделать так что бы `progressbar` увеличивался исходя от остатка времени копирования?

Так же интересует и с архивом

```
shutil.make_archive("test archive", "zip", src)
```

Comment: я отвечал на похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950783/shutil-copytree-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/950819#950819 . Думаю, это то, что вам надо. Если что-то не так - напишите.

Comment: @S.Nick Спасибо изучил код. Почти все понятно кроме self.ActionValue.emit(final_total * 100 // self.sizeOrigin)  
                QtCore.QThread.msleep(10) почему тут нужно что бы потом засыпал?

Comment: Чтобы дополнительный поток не грузил ЦП на 100% 
 и у вас была возможность обрабатывать события основного потока.
 Если мой ответ, в том вопросе, помог вам, вы можете отметить его как полезный.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, все решено ?